# android regex for plates

Tags: java, android

I want to generate a regex in android to check plate numbers like

3 letters 1 space and 4 decimal numbers

```
LLL NNNN
```

Comment: `[L]{3}\ [N]{4}` [Example](http://rubular.com/r/uLTPUPsyGh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will be `[a-zA-Z]{3}\\s[\\d]{4}` as Java string